# Keeping the sidebar panel expanded on a redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have expansion panels in my sidenav and I'm keeping track of their open state and setting it. So as a different panel is opened, the state changes to reflect the panel that is open. Within my panel I have list items that on click redirect to another route. My problem is I want to keep the panel where the list item clicked open on the redirect. On the redirect to the list item route, a refresh happens and the sidenav goes back to its original state which is obviously expansion panels collapsed. The list has an on click that does a react Redirect to the path.

Answer (score 0):

*Answering your question without regard to React:*

Store the panel state in `.localStorage` upon state change:

```
localStorage.setItem('panelState',JSON.stringify(myStateObj));
```

Upon `.DOMContentLoaded` retrieve and restore the state:

```
restoreState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('panelState')));
```

*If you are using React, one has to wonder why you are not using it as a SPA, but that is for another Q&A I suppose*

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this? I know how to store the panel state in .localstorage. I don't understand the .DomContentLoaded and where I'd put that. Where does that code belong. In the component did mount of my sidenav class? I'm kind of confused about that. Also, it is a single page app. The routes are programatically created through the Gatsby API.

Comment: My answer is moot if it is a SPA. This statement is confusing: _**On the redirect to the list item route, a refresh happens and the sidenav goes back to its original state which is obviously expansion panels collapsed.**_. You should be maintaining state in a component.

Comment: But I am, which is why I'm confused as to why when the redirect happens the sidenav collapses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a layout with a left and right sections. Keep the state in main component and when something is clicked, update the right side that is the content section. That should do the trick without any hassle

Answer (score 0):

I would say use redux or some state management lib if you have installed already its best.
another best way would be using a layout page in your main file i.e. app.js and load your routers in layout body and your layout state management will be in state management.